# Rails respond_with always returns status code 200 despite specifying 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple action to test if a promo code exists and return it if so :

```
class PromoCodesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def check
    code = params[:code]

    @promo_code = PromoCode.where(code: code).uniq

    if @promo_code
      respond_with @promo_code
    else
      respond_with nil, status: :not_found
    end
  end

end
```

When it doesn't exist, I thought I would just return a 404 status code, but I always get a 200 when looking at the network tab of the dev tools.

Any reason this is happening ? Would it be bad practice to return a 404 in this case ?

I'm on Rails 4.

Comment: You're checking for nil on `@promo_code` however your query `PromoCode.where(...).uniq` will never return nil (at worst it will return an empty ActiveRecord relation). You either need to check for the presence of records with `@promo_code.present?` or change your query to find a single record with `PromoCode.find_by(code: code)`. This will either find the code or raise a 404 exception.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, I changed to a `find_by` and replaced the `respond_with` block with this single line : `respond_with @promo_code, status: @promo_code.nil? ? :not_found : :ok`. So this means you need a `nil` response to issue a `404` status code ?

Comment: Please read Rog's response and upvote.  `PromoCode.where(code: code).uniq` returns a collection and `if @promo_code` only checks for non nil values.  Since an empty collection is not nil you will respond with a 200 and an empty collection.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, things got confused when writing the precedent comment. Rog if you want to post the answer I will accept it. Otherwise I will do it.